# Link and button height not the same in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a link and a button sitting next to each other on a page. The CSS code effecting them is identical, but the input is just a bit shorter in height than the input - any suggestions about how to make them the exact same height? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9gg7ncu/)

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Input"> <a href="#">Link</a>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"], a:link, a:visited {
background-color: #4eb4df;
border: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #6d6d6d;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px auto 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:active, a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #3e94b9;
}
```

Comment: Just make the value of the link and button the same. The text sets the width. Why do you need them to be the exact same width?

Comment: I should have stated my question better - I'm actually looking for them to be the same height, not the same width. Sorry about that!

Comment: They are the same height already. I even checked in the web inspector. I'm using Safari 9.

Comment: This is what it shows in Firefox: [screenshot](http://smallemperor.com/screenshot.png)

Comment: It's a bug with Firefox! Please see my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox appears to render the height of input elements differently than other browsers. This is very annoying but the code below explains about how to remove the added height.

I did some research and figured it out. It appears to be a bug with Firefox. Here is a another question which covers it [Buttons too tall on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859908/buttons-too-tall-on-firefox). Here is an article which explains with more information http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-buttons.

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/www139/e9gg7ncu/2/.

Here is a code snippet (remember that this is only relevant to the Firefox browser).

```css
input[type="submit"], a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #4eb4df;
    border: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #6d6d6d;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px auto 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:1em;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:active, a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #3e94b9;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner /*Remove button padding in FF*/
{ 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Input"> <a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The link is shorter because the text on it is shorter. If you want to force a width, You can add a value of `width` or `min-width`. In this case you will also want to get rid of the left and right padding, and probably align the text in the center.

```
input[type="submit"], a:link, a:visited {
    min-width: 100px
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I meant that I want them to be the same height, not the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the class to the following, set the width to be the same and make sure you use box-sizing so that the width and height includes content, padding and border.

```
input[type="submit"], a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #4eb4df;
    border: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #6d6d6d;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px auto 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    width:250px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks so much for your help, but I actually need them to be the same height, not the same width.

Comment: Oh haha, well according to the inspecter they both have 32px height

Comment: This is what it shows in Firefox: [screenshot](http://smallemperor.com/screenshot.png)

Comment: I don't have firefox on this computer, but try playing with the height properties and box-sizing in css. Specifying positioning may also help.