# CSS: Styling an input element's text (as opposed to the input element itself)?

Tags: html, css, input

EDIT: I've added the relevant code below at the bottom of this question. As you'll see there, the button is wrapped within a div. Also, this problem only occurs in one browser, that being Firefox, and I'll be using a hack to target that browser only.

I have an input element of type *submit* (i.e., basically a submit button). The text displayed in this element, as defined in the element's *value* attribute, appears too low (i.e., too close to the bottom of the button instead of vertically centered). The button has a fixed height.

Naturally, I want to move the button's text, as defined in the *value* attribute, one or two pixels upwards.

I've tried a few things with the button's padding (top and bottom), but that didn't change anything. [Is that to be expected, BTW?] Therefore, I would like to use relative positioning to move the text upwards a bit.

The thing is, however, that I need to target the text itself, NOT the input/button element. And that's of course because the button itself should stay at its current location, I only want to move the TEXT displayed on the button.

Thus my question: Is there a way, in CSS, to target not the button but only its displayed text (as defined in the *value* attribute) ?

Of course, other solutions (preferably CSS only) are welcome as well.

Code:

HTML:

```
<form id="zoekform">
   <input type="text" class=""  id="search-text" name="search-text" placeholder="Search"> 
   <div class="erom" id="erom2">
      <input id="zoekknop" style="float: right" type="submit" method="GET" value="Search!" />
   </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#zoekform {
    height: 29px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
 }

 .erom {
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

   #erom2 {
      border: solid 1px #452F5D;
      width: 27%;
      display: inline-block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   #zoekknop {
      float: right;
      height: 100%;
      color: white;
      font-size: 19px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #446666;
      color: white;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      border: solid 1px white;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

And finally the part where I'm targeting Firefox only, and where I can't get the padding working (and to be sure, the "media query" (it's not really a media query) does work, and in any case I've also tried this without the media query, i.e. as part of the regular CSS):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
#zoekknop {
padding-top: -1px !important;
padding-bottom: 9px !important; // I set it to 9px for now, so that I could clearly see if it worked
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to target the text ? Your task can be done perfectly using the padding property of the button element !

Comment: Try adding the `line-height:` attribute in the CSS.

Comment: @SKG OK, maybe I should try again, and I will... But I did try using padding already and it didn't seem to work. Maybe there was another issue.

Comment: Why not you share your code here ?, That will make it easier to answer your problem.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that, will take a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason form elements are particular and quirky about font.

- Assign a font to the `<submit>`'s parent, then use `font: inherit` on the `<submit>` button.
- On the `<submit>` assign `line-height` of `1.4` to `2` (notice there's no unit like `px` or `em`.) I actually have the `line-height` assigned by inheriting the font from `<form>` `1.4`.
- Set `width` using the `ex` unit of measurement. One `ex` is as wide as a`x` character, making it a great way of gauging how much space you are using in relation to your text. I used `9ex` for a 6 character word (i.e. Submit).
- This ruleset may help you for Firefox:

  ```
   input::-moz-focus-inner {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;

      /* Some users have said these last two are 
         unnecessary or should be -2px */ 

      margin-top:0;  
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  ```

Here's some changes I did to your button and search field:

```
     #zoekknop {....
        ....
        border: 2px double white;
        line-height: 1.65;
        vertical-align: baseline;
      }

      #search-text {
         line-height: 1.75;
         vertical-align: baseline;
         padding: 4px 3px 0;
       }
```

Review the Snippet below:

```css
#form {
  font: 400 16px/1.4'Verdana';
}
#form .sub {
  font: inherit;
  width: 9ex;
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#form .sub:hover {
  color: cyan;
  background: #888;
}
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

#zoekform {
  height: 29px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font: 400 16px/1.4 'Verdana';
}
#zoekform #zoekknop {
  
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #446666;
  color: white;
  
  border: 2px double white;
  line-height: 1.65;
  vertical-align: baseline;

}
#search-text {
  line-height: 1.75;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  padding: 4px 3px 0
}
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="form">
  <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="zoekform">
  <input type="text" class="" id="search-text" name="search-text" placeholder="Search">
  
    <input id="zoekknop" type="submit" method="GET" value="Search!" />
  
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this asap. For now, I'll edit my question to add the relevant code.

Comment: No prob, take your time, no rush. There might be a better answer later on.

Comment: I've now simply added your above rule-set for Firefox, and that makes a difference of 1 pixel, which makes things look very presentable (and I think can in fact be seen as vertically centered, since the button is not very high and placing the text one more pixel higher may not improve things). I'll  give you an upvote for that, and may well accept the answer as a whole later on. It's an interesting rule for sure, haven't seen this before.

Comment: Thanks, it's a Firefox pseudo-bug a couple of years back. https://davidwalsh.name/firefox-buttons and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859908/buttons-too-tall-on-firefox

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, because it basically solved my issue. However, I HOPE to be able to report more extensively later on (in a few weeks' time) on what exactly is going on here, and also why padding didn't seem to work here (if I manage to find out the reason). Thanks again and I'll be sure to check out the links you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
This should work
#buttonID{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;//pushes text up inside the button
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to tweak a bit, but I'll report back later today.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define the height, width, line-height, font-size, and padding of the button. Then you should be able to manipulate the padding and line-height to get the result you want. It sounds like the button may be inheriting a line height that is causing the issue.

Targeting the text itself isn't the way to go about this. Would be helpful to see the CSS and HTML of the button, and note which browser the issue appears in.

Comment: Thanks. The browser is Firefox (IE and Chrome display fine, not testing mobile browsers at this stage).  I'll see if I can edit the answer to add the relevant code, but this may take several minutes.