# Weird styling applied to buttons in Firefox v60

Tags: css, firefox

In Firefox, the `<button>` element has a default browser styling applied to it that I can't quite understand. The inspector says it has a 17px left and right border.

Here is how it looks when inspecting it:

[image]
[image]
[image]

and when filtering to show browser styles as well:

[image]

What's interesting is that it says `border-right-width  17px`, but collapsing the rule reveals `button > 2px` from the browser default styles `forms.css:611`. That line of the stylesheet clearly states that the border should be 2px:

```
/* Non text-related properties for buttons: these ones are shared with
input[type="color"] */
button,
input[type="color"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -moz-appearance: button;
  /* The sum of border and padding on block-start and block-end
     must be the same here, for text inputs, and for <select>.
     Note -moz-focus-inner padding does not affect button size. */
  padding-block-start: 0px;
  padding-inline-end: 8px;
  padding-block-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 8px;
  border: 2px outset ThreeDLightShadow;
  background-color: ButtonFace;
  cursor: default;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -moz-binding: none;
}
```

So what's going on here? Am I missing something obvious?

Again, this is Firefox v60.0.2 on Debian.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35858396/2813224), it might help.

Comment: @zer00ne thanks for the input, but I am not looking for a workaround to actually styling the button. I am just wondering why this happens, if it is a bug or if I am missing something.

Comment: it's an old bug

Comment: Your OS has fewer users and fewer problems than most :)

Comment: @zer00ne actually, this still appears in latest Firefox (version 66).